# out of memory java heap exception

Tags: shell

I am getting out of memory java heap exception while running my java code in unix environment.

I have bash shell script which invokes java class,within few seconsds after running the script im getting the error.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Below is my shell script.

```
home_dir=/opt/IBM/IEEP/MigrationBatch
java_home=/opt/IBM/WAS/java
lib_path=$home_dir/lib
job_path=$home_dir/bin/jobs
config_path=$home_dir/bin/config

batch_root_path=$home_dir
root_path=$batch_root_path/migration

mkdir -p $root_path
mkdir -p $root_path/working

log_date=$(date +%m%d%Y_%H%M%S)
run_date=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)
job_name="MigrationBatch"

script_log_path=$root_path/script_logs
logfile=$script_log_path/script_log_migration_txt_$log_date.txt
mkdir -p $script_log_path
echo "Script Log Files available at $logfile"
exec>>$logfile
echo "Starting Java process for MigrationBatch Job...."

## STEP 1 : Run the Java Job
export JAR_HOME=$lib_path
export JOB_HOME=$job_path
export CONFIG_HOME=$config_path

JAR_CLASSPATH=:$lib_path/activation-1.1.jar:
echo $JAR_CLASSPATH

$java_home/bin/java -Djob_name=$job_name - Drun_timestamp=$run_date -cp $JAR_CLASSPATH:$job_path:$config_path org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner migrationJob.xml  migrationJob -next

script_output="$(echo $?)"
```

Comment: Is the long string of spaces between `-` and `Drun_timestamp...` intentional?

Comment: @chepner. while copy paste it got the space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not your shell out of memory, this be your java command line execution you could try:

```
 java -Xmx1024m -jar jarfie
 java -Xms512m -Xmx2g -jar somejar
 $java_home/bin/java -Xms512m -Xmx2g -Djob_name=$job_name -Drun_timestamp=$run_date -cp $JAR_CLASSPATH:$job_path:$config_path org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner migrationJob.xml migrationJob -next
```

You may need to increase more if it still gives you memory issues

Comment: I understand its java exception while calling the below java class from shell script. $java_home/bin/java -Djob_name=$job_name -Drun_timestamp=$run_date -cp $JAR_CLASSPATH:$job_path:$config_path org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner migrationJob.xml migrationJob -next. Any suggestion on how to fix it would be helpful.

Comment: i have added the following arg after java -Xms512M -Xmx1524M

Comment: It still failed - try enabling additional options and running manually to see what happens: java -verbose -verbose:class -verbose:gc -Xms2g -Xmx2g -Djob_name=$job_name -Drun_timestamp=$run_date -cp $JAR_CLASSPATH:$job_path:$config_path org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner migrationJob.xml migrationJob -next

Comment: also worth checking overall machines memory to see how much free memory you have and if for example 2 gig is actually free to assign a 2 gig size

Comment: No worries what was the issue